# mpdf file laravel 5.8 , An error occurs when playing some pdf files while others are working fine Carry it out using the framework laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf, mpdf

> An error occurs when playing some pdf files while others are working
>   fine Carry it out using the framework laravel
>   error:

**setasign \ Fpdi \ PdfParser \ CrossReference \ CrossReferenceException (267)
This PDF document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI. (See https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details)**

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

use App\Sort_table;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem ;

class PDFController extends Controller{
public  function showFilepdf($file){





  $path= storage_path("app\public\upload\\".$file->textPDF);

  //$numberpage=$request->input("numberpage");
  $numberpage=1;

       // $pdfid =pdf::find($id);

        // create a log channel
        $logger = new Logger('name');
        $logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('your.log', Logger::DEBUG));

        $pdf = new Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/mytemp'] ,['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);
     $pdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');

       // $mpdf->setLogger($logger);

     $pdf->SetDocTemplate($path,false);

      $i=0;
       while($i<=1000){

        $pdf->AddPage('L','A','L','L','L',50,50,50,50,10,10);
       $i++;
       }
       $pdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

        // Subsequent pages from logoheader.pdf will be inserted on all subsequent pages


          //Make sure path exists
          if (!file_exists($path)) {
              mkdir($path, 0777);
          }

           $pdf->Output();





}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the library used to import the PDFs for mPDF ([FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/)) can only read up to version 1.4 of the PDF specification. Anything higher than this is not supported and will generate the error you've noted.

There is a commercial parser for FPDI that does include full support reading later version of the PDF specification - 1.5 to 1.7 (the latest) - which you might find useful: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/